# TR background color merges with Table background color

Tags: html, css, class, html-table, tr

Having strange trouble the first time in my life, have a table with

```
table.csr-table td:first-child {
    width: 70px;
    background: rgba(84, 46, 121, .2);
}
```

which changes the color of all first cells of column, now I have another class

```
.headerCell,.headerRow {
    background: rgba(84, 46, 121, .2);
}
```

which also has similar background color, but when both are applied by the rule the color merge themselves and make a new color, 
I want to avoid that please help

Comment: Do you really need the "opacity" field in the rgba() ?  Making that ".2" a "1" or even completely remove it could resolve the issue. I can't be more precise without the full code.

Comment: yes you are right about it but as you know the designer are very explicit about the colors, any other solution

Comment: I don't think you can accomplish what you want without making one of the colors solid. Having both of them with any other alpha other than 1 will make them merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a solid colour for the  like rgb(221,213,228) rather than one with transparency (alpha). You should be able to find the correct value from your designs, or the designer can give it to you?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `rgba` and the `a` stands for `alpha`. The `alpha` applies transparency to the color, so when there are more than one color they will merge.
You can use `rgb` (at least for second color) instead.

Comment: still getting darker